# Why are static GWT fields not transferred to the client?

Tags: gwt

`ConfigProperty.idPropertyMap` is filled on the server side. (verified via log output)

Accessing it on the client side shows it's empty. :-( (verified via log output)

Is this some default behaviour? (I don't think so)
Is the problem maybe related to the inner class `ConfigProperty.IdPropertyMap`, `java.util.HashMap` usage, serialization or some field access modifier issue?

Thanks for your help

```
    // the transfer object

    public class ConfigProperty implements IsSerializable, Comparable {

        ...

    static public class IdPropertyMap extends HashMap 
             implements IsSerializable 
        {
           ...
        }

    protected static IdPropertyMap idPropertyMap = new IdPropertyMap();

        ...
    }


    // the server service

    public class ManagerServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        ManagerService 
    {
        ...

        public IdPropertyMap getConfigProps(String timeToken) 
            throws ConfiguratorException 
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

added from below after some good answers (thanks!):

**answer bottom line**: static field sync is not implemented/supported currently. someone/me would have to file a feature request

just my perspective (an fallen-in-love newby to GWT :-)):

I understand pretty good (not perfect! ;-)) the possible implications of "global" variable syncing (a dependency graph or usage of annotations could be useful).
But from a new (otherwise experienced Java EE/web) user it looks like this:

- you create some `myapp.shared.dto.MyClass` class (dto = data transfer objects)
- you add some static fields in it that just represent collections of those objects (and maybe some other DTOs)
- you can also do this on the client side and all the other static methods work as well
- only thing not working is synchronization (which is not sooo bad in the first place)

BUT: some provided annotation, let's say `@Transfer static Collection<MyClass> myObjList;` would be handy, since I seem to know the impact and benefits that this would bring.

In my case it's rather simple since the client is more static, but would like to have this data without explicitely implementing it if the GWT framework could do it.

Comment: changing `protected ... idPropertyMap` to `public ...` did not help.

Comment: btw. I am using GWT 2.5.0, runtime code is JRE 6 compatible, internal Jetty on jre7x64bit, Eclipse Juno 64bit on 64bit jre7x64bit JVM, Win7 64bit

Comment: You may add your comments to the original post.

Comment: @Artemix: did just this. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

static variables are purely class variable It has nothing to do with individual instances. serialization applies only to object.

So ,your are getting always empty a ConfigProperty.idPropertyMap

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if something like this is considered to be implemented? Since JavaScript supports kind of static methods/fields it should be possible - not considering other potential problems.

Comment: I also like to mention here that it is hard to find that fact in the docs via googleing! This was not so obvious to me since static methods ARE usable on both sides.

Comment: They are usable on each side, but just like any other method of sending data, they don't travel over the wire - look at message passing systems for either JSON or Java Beans and you will see that this is not unusual.

Comment: Actually I never tried this, but you want to preserve the value of  
ConfigProperty.idPropertyMap during serialization should save and restore these values explicitly using private void readObject(ObjectInputStream) and private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream)

Comment: I don't believe `ObjectOutputStream` can be used in a GWT project - client code is limited to classes that can be translated to JavaScript.

Comment: yes, it's mistake, of course It can not possible to use a client side. I just try to explain him how to serialize a static variable in java. it divert on other topic.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of RPC is not that you can act as though the client and the server are exactly the same JVM, but that they can share the objects that you pass over the wire. To send a static field over the wire, from the server to the client, the object stored in that field must be returned from the RPC method.

Static properties are not serialized and sent over the wire, because they do not belong to a single object, but to the class itself.

```
public class MyData implements Serializable {
    protected String name;//sent over the wire, each MyData has its own name
    protected String key;

    protected static String masterKey;//All objects on the server or client 
    // share this, it cannot be sent over RPC. Instead, another RPC method
    // could access it
}
```

Note, however, that it will only be that one instance which will be shared - if something else on the server changes that field, all clients which have asked for a copy will need to be updated

Comment: I would argue that the implemented RPC idea is in a way exactly this. But I understand the limitations of course. I mean all the JRE emulation classes are proof of the "idea".

Comment: The principle is only that objects are sent, not global data - the static field isn't a part of any one object, so must not be sent. Consider what would happen if I downloaded MyData from RPC, referenced masterKey from several places in my app, then loaded a different MyData, and the server had changed masterKey - should all other parts of the app somehow magically know that the value had changed? Look at how JSON works for JS apps - it doesn't modify global variables when a single object gets an update.

Comment: Thx Colin. It makes sense if you stick to the established view - which maybe the right way to see it. Its just when one takes a step back and forgets about which reasons there had been in the past, you may see the way everything works differently. (Meaning: It could make sense to "try" to (auto-)sync static fields (as well) between client and server if the programmer is aware of the implications. It could lower the complexity of "hidden" client-server handling in going further on the path to make web apps be programmed like desktop ones.)